# HA Proxy: Omit basic auth for specific URIs

Tags: haproxy, http-basic-authentication

Given a userlist such...

```
userlist UsersAuth
  group admin users foo
  user foo insecure-password bar
```

And a backend containing this...

```
acl AuthOkay_Web http_auth(UsersAuth)
  http-request auth realm AuthYourself if !isOptions !AuthOkay_Web
```

How can I specify one or more URIs that DO NOT require basic auth?

So, given...

```
https://example.com/a
https://example.com/baz
https://example.com/c
https://example.com/d
```

Let's assume that I want `/baz` to get a free pass.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the ACL documentation at https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#7.1.3, I came up with this...

```
  acl url_static path_beg /baz
  acl AuthOkay_Web http_auth(UsersAuth)
  http-request auth realm AuthYourself if !isOptions !url_static !AuthOkay_Web
```